# How to Prevent Access From Freezing When Pasting PDF Picture Into OLE Object

Tags: image, ms-access, pdf, ms-access-2007, oledb

I have a form in Access where users paste images into an OLE object and then after clicking a button it exports the pictures to a file on a network drive to be recalled later. This works fine for screen shots and copying things out of paint, but recently a user tried to paste a picture copied out of a PDF file and the form locked up (no buttons would work and I couldn't highlight any fields or change combo boxes). The picture still shows in the OLE object and oddly enough you can still cut the picture out and the form returns to normal. There was no error thrown and it appears that the only form that is affected is the one the picture was pasted into (other tabs in Access still function properly).

Is there any way to prevent the form from freezing when pasting from a PDF or to detect what the user is trying to paste in order to prevent it/throw an error message up to alert the user?

FYI: No code is run in Access when the picture is pasted into the OLE object frame, so I suspect this is an issue with Access.